# Matlab convert image from gray to binary

Tags: matlab, image-processing

İn Matlab, I want to threshold a grayscale image to convert it to a black & white image:

```
for k=1:Y
  for i=1:X
    if gray(i,k)>T
      gray(i,k)=1;
    else
      gray(i,k)=0;
    end
  end
end
```

What do you think should be the value of T?

Comment: Picking a value for T (and actually, picking just *one* value in particular) is really a pretty hard problem, last time I looked there were fresh research papers on the subject.

Comment: Additionally, it is very dependent on your application and the nature of the particular data you'll be working with. Can you expand your problem description a bit?

Comment: As they've mentioned, binarization algorithms are legion.  For a simple example that uses global thresholding, you could try an old stand-by, Otsu's method: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu's_method  But no one is going to be able to tell you a good value for T without actually looking at your data.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do with the output. Is it for humans to see? what to do some machine detection? print? projection? ...

Comment: Also go to dsp.stackexchange.com for this kind of questions! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I were you, I would use the median:

```
gray=double(gray>median(gray(:)))
```

PS: you should use this more efficient code in general:

```
gray=double(gray>T)
```

Comment: This is a very bad idea. A typical text book page with graphics could be 60% white, 30% grayscale image and 10% text. The median of the page would be pure white!, so your image would be solid black.

Comment: Of course, there is no one single simple solution that fits all cases. However, using median can perform okay in many scenarios. So, it is not a "very bad idea". Your case where more than half of the image is saturated is quite rare.

Answer (score 0):

Inbuilt function im2bw takes level as one of the parameters. So instead of using for loops we can use it for conversion. Default level is 0.5.

From: http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2bw.html

im2bw

Convert image to binary image, based on threshold

Syntax

```
BW = im2bw(I, level)
BW = im2bw(X, map, level)
BW = im2bw(RGB, level)
```

Answer (score 0):

Dusty's answer of using Otsu's method is built-in in MATLAB.

The following code is from the MATLAB page about the [graythresh](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/graythresh.html) function (which implements Otsu's method).

```
I = imread('coins.png');
level = graythresh(I);
BW = im2bw(I,level);
imshow(BW)
```